# Best Practice on animation multiple Actions for a game character

Tags: animation, pose-mode, actions

I want to ask, what is the most proper approach for handling rest pose in actions. Do I need to just set the keyframes for ALL of my bones at frame 0 for each Action? Or is there a better way to reset the pose?

For example, I made 3 Actions and didn't use the neck bone in all of them, now I want to add 4th Action with this bone involved. So now I need to go back to 3 of my previous Actions and add this bone at frame 0 with the rest-pose parameters. I don't know, this seems like a wrong way to animate.

Comment: if you don't want the bone to get its loc/rot/scale from the previous action, yes, keyframe it in the other actions

Comment: Thank you, I'm doing it already, just thought that there was a better approach to this.

Comment: I'm not sure that there's any option in the NLA that can reset the bone action if the bone is not keyframed but I may be wrong